# Animation extremely slow for threejs animation when calling requestAnimationFrame from within class

Tags: javascript, class, three.js, this, requestanimationframe

The best way to describe this issue is to checkout the JSFiddle.  The animation will be very choppy when you try to move around the mouse or do anything.  I've narrowed it down to having something to do with classing this.requestAnimationFrame(this.animation) which didn't work at first, but after looking on stackoverflow I discovered a fix to say `this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);` This made it work but extremely slow! **How can I make this faster while retaining the class?**

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gentleman_goat66/o5wn3bpf/100/

Here is my code below:

HTML

```
<script type="importmap">
{
"imports": 
  {
    "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/build/three.module.js",
    "OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
  }
}
</script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

JS

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';

class Heatmap {
  constructor(){
    console.log("Heatmap - constructor()");
    
    //ThreeJS Variables
    this.camera = null;
    this.scene = null;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    this.orbital_controls = null;
    this.ambientLight = null;
    this.heatmap = new THREE.Object3D(); //This will hold all the meshes that make up the heatmap
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
    
    //Animation Related Variables
    this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
    this.delta = 0;
    this.fps = 60; //60 fps
        this.interval = 1;
        this.seconds = 2; //seconds for animation
        this.timeSoFar = 0;
        this.targetTime = 3;
    
    //Setup
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.setUpCamera();
    this.setUpRenderer();
    this.setUpLighting();
    this.setUpOrbitalControls();
    
    //Add optional GridHelper for Debug
    this.scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());
    
    //TODO: Create the heatmap here
    this.createDataRectangle();
    
    //Add the finished heatmap to the scene
    this.scene.add(this.heatmap);
    this.render();
    this.animate();
  }
  setUpRenderer(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpRenderer()");
    let width = $('#container').width();
    let height = $('#container').height();
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(width,height);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
 
    $("#container").html(this.renderer.domElement);
    
    window.addEventListener("resize", event => {
      this.camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      this.renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    });
  }
  setUpCamera(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpCamera()");
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 100);
    this.camera.position.z = 4;
  }
  setUpLighting(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpLighting()");
    this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.scene.add(this.ambientLight);
  }
  setUpOrbitalControls(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpOrbitalControls()");
    this.orbital_controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
    this.orbital_controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    this.orbital_controls.enableDamping = true;
    this.orbital_controls.dampingFactor = 0.025;
    this.orbital_controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2.0;
    this.orbital_controls.minDistance = 2.0;
    this.orbital_controls.maxDistance = 80.0;
    this.orbital_controls.update();
    
    this.orbital_controls.addEventListener( 'change', function(){
      if (this.target.y < 0){
          this.target.y = 0;
          /* camera.position.y = -1; */
      } else if (this.target.y > 1){
          this.target.y = 1;
          /* camera.position.y = 1; */
      }
    });
  }
  createDataRectangle(){ //TODO: Make this create at a position specified
    console.log("Heatmap - createDataRectangle()");
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    const vertices = [
      -2, 0, 1,//0, floor, bottom left
      -1, 0, 1,//1, floor, bottom right
      -1, 0, -1,//2, floor, top right
      -2, 0, -1,//3 floor, top left
      -2, 0, 1,//4 roof, bottom left
      -1, 0, 1,//5 roof, bottom right
      -1, 0, -1,//6 roof, top right
      -2, 0, -1//7 roof, top left
    ];
    const indices = [
      0, 1, 2,//floor, first triangle
      2, 3, 0,//floor, second triangle
      4, 5, 6,//roof, first triangle
      6, 7, 4,//roof, second triangle
      3, 0, 4,//west wall, first triangle
      3, 4, 7,//west wall, second triangle
      0, 1, 5,//south wall, first triangle
      0, 5, 4,//south wall, first triangle
      1, 2, 6,//east wall, first triangle
      1, 6, 5,//east wall, second triangle
      2, 3, 7,//north wall, first triangle
      2, 7, 6,//north wall, second triangle
    ];
    const colors = [
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0,  // top left
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0  // top left
    ];
    geometry.setIndex(indices);
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({side:THREE.FrontSide,vertexColors:true,color: 0xFFFFFF });
    const sample_rectangle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.heatmap.add(sample_rectangle);
  }
  animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame( this.animate);

    this.orbital_controls.update();//Required for Damping on OrbitControls

    this.delta += this.clock.getDelta();

    if (this.delta  > this.interval) {
      //this.timeSoFar = this.timeSoFar + (1 * morphDirection);

      this.render();
      this.delta = this.delta % this.interval;
    }
  }
  render(){
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("DOM ready!");
  new Heatmap();
});
```

CSS

```
body,html{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what were you expecting the

```js
this.delta += this.clock.getDelta();
if (this.delta  > this.interval) {
```

part would do. But this is your issue, `this.interval = 1` here means that the part in the `if` block will get executed only once every second.
Maybe you wanted to limit to some FPS, in which case you should have had `this.interval = 1 / this.fps;` but I don't see a good reason to do this, since limiting to a fixed FPS is VERY hard to get right (you must choose a multiple of the active monitor's native refresh rate, <sub>and with variable rate monitors...</sub>)
So the best is probably to get rid of this check entirely and run as fast as the monitor and browser are willing to go.

```css
body,html{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">
{
"imports": 
  {
    "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/build/three.module.js",
    "OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
  }
}
</script>
<div id="container">
</div>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';

class Heatmap {
  constructor(){
    console.log("Heatmap - constructor()");
    
    //ThreeJS Variables
    this.camera = null;
    this.scene = null;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    this.orbital_controls = null;
    this.ambientLight = null;
    this.heatmap = new THREE.Object3D(); //This will hold all the meshes that make up the heatmap
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
    
        this.seconds = 2; //seconds for animation
        this.timeSoFar = 0;
        this.targetTime = 3;
    
    //Setup
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.setUpCamera();
    this.setUpRenderer();
    this.setUpLighting();
    this.setUpOrbitalControls();
    
    //Add optional GridHelper for Debug
    this.scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());
    
    //TODO: Create the heatmap here
    this.createDataRectangle();
    
    //Add the finished heatmap to the scene
    this.scene.add(this.heatmap);
    this.render();
    this.animate();
  }
  setUpRenderer(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpRenderer()");
    let width = $('#container').width();
    let height = $('#container').height();
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(width,height);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
 
    $("#container").html(this.renderer.domElement);
    
    window.addEventListener("resize", event => {
      this.camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      this.renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    });
  }
  setUpCamera(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpCamera()");
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 100);
    this.camera.position.z = 4;
  }
  setUpLighting(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpLighting()");
    this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.scene.add(this.ambientLight);
  }
  setUpOrbitalControls(){
    console.log("Heatmap - setUpOrbitalControls()");
    this.orbital_controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
    this.orbital_controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    this.orbital_controls.enableDamping = true;
    this.orbital_controls.dampingFactor = 0.025;
    this.orbital_controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2.0;
    this.orbital_controls.minDistance = 2.0;
    this.orbital_controls.maxDistance = 80.0;
    this.orbital_controls.update();
    
    this.orbital_controls.addEventListener( 'change', function(){
      if (this.target.y < 0){
          this.target.y = 0;
          /* camera.position.y = -1; */
      } else if (this.target.y > 1){
          this.target.y = 1;
          /* camera.position.y = 1; */
      }
    });
  }
  createDataRectangle(){ //TODO: Make this create at a position specified
    console.log("Heatmap - createDataRectangle()");
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    const vertices = [
      -2, 0, 1,//0, floor, bottom left
      -1, 0, 1,//1, floor, bottom right
      -1, 0, -1,//2, floor, top right
      -2, 0, -1,//3 floor, top left
      -2, 0, 1,//4 roof, bottom left
      -1, 0, 1,//5 roof, bottom right
      -1, 0, -1,//6 roof, top right
      -2, 0, -1//7 roof, top left
    ];
    const indices = [
      0, 1, 2,//floor, first triangle
      2, 3, 0,//floor, second triangle
      4, 5, 6,//roof, first triangle
      6, 7, 4,//roof, second triangle
      3, 0, 4,//west wall, first triangle
      3, 4, 7,//west wall, second triangle
      0, 1, 5,//south wall, first triangle
      0, 5, 4,//south wall, first triangle
      1, 2, 6,//east wall, first triangle
      1, 6, 5,//east wall, second triangle
      2, 3, 7,//north wall, first triangle
      2, 7, 6,//north wall, second triangle
    ];
    const colors = [
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0,  // top left
      2,0,0, // bottom left
      0,2,0, // bottom right
      0,2,0, // top right
      2,0,0  // top left
    ];
    geometry.setIndex(indices);
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({side:THREE.FrontSide,vertexColors:true,color: 0xFFFFFF });
    const sample_rectangle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.heatmap.add(sample_rectangle);
  }
  animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);

    this.orbital_controls.update();//Required for Damping on OrbitControls
    this.render();
  }
  render(){
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("DOM ready!");
  new Heatmap();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I apologize, I feel like an idiot, it was supposed to be / fps when I was converting to a class and I forgot this step... I did however, find a better way to do the this.animate part where it would not give an error for those wondering, requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.animate()
    }); , doing it this way gets rid of that error and was still super fast.  But indeed the main issue was what you pointed out!

Comment: Using .bind or the anonymous function are relatively the same, with the bound function creating slightly less garbage per frame, this has never been your performance bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, you are right that was not the performance bottleneck, was just pointing out that, the this.animate done that way seemed to work, but if bound is better I am curious as to why that is? I could put it back to that way if so.

Comment: Neither is "better" than the other, they're relatively the same. Using `bind()` will just avoid creating one new function every frame, which means less garbage to be collected, and thus, maybe, less interruptions of the Garbage Collector, possibly blocking the CPU for more than a frame. But for that to happen on modern devices you'd have to run your animation for hours. If you want my opinion, my preferred  way of doing is to extract the animation loop out of the class and have it call the instances update method. This way no problem with `this`.